# Trac + SVN: Why post commit hook doesn't work?

Tags: linux, svn, trac

I want to use the standard Trac post-commit-hook for SVN.

I'm using Trac 0.11.4 and have downloaded [this hook](http://trac.edgewall.org/export/8885/tags/trac-0.11.4/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook) from their site. I've put it into `/usr/local/bin/` and `chmod +x`'ed it.
The `post-commit` hook in `/var/svn/myrepo/hooks/` looks just as Trac Guide advises:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
TRAC_ENV="/var/trac/mytracenv"
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/trac-post-commit-hook -p "$TRAC_ENV" -r "$REV"
```

Trac environment directory `/var/trac/mytracenv` is writable for Subversion user. I'm running standalone `svnserve`, no Apache.

If I run
`/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/trac-post-commit-hook -p /var/trac/mytracenv -r <somerev>`
manually as Subversion user, it works as it should. However if I do a commit (using TortoiseSVN) it says:

`Error post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output.`

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem is permission-related.
Make sure both the `post-commit` script and the `rac-post-commit-hook` have the proper privileges. If it works for you using the command line, try to do it as the user that is running the svn daemon (`sudo -u svnuser [cmd]`).

I could fix a similar problem a year or so ago by adding "chmod o+x" both of the scripts.

Comment: It must have been permission issue indeed. I chmoded both scripts and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

let's 'set -x' in the script for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the environment variables; one of the most common causes is not having the `$PATH` you expect.

Comment: That's why I'm using absolute paths.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking there was something inside the `trac-post-commit-hook` that might be affected by that, but glancing over it again, I don't see anything.  You might add an `echo` to the post-commit hook to verify that part is getting executed.